# what is the best way to upload images to server? save in database or in server folder?

Tags: asp.net, browser-cache

the problem is browser's cache method where they only can cache images that have server patch, look like: http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackexchange/img/logos/se/se-logo.png

in other hand, if we save images in SQl-server, we have more control(delete, update, search,...) and maintenance ability on images and its other information. but the browsers downloads every time i access it from database.
**is there a way to cache images that is loaded from database(asp-c#)?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not both? You can save path reference in database (along some other useful information about the image such as tags, size, etc.).

Then you can have a controller for your images (update / search / delete) and use .

If you do so, images are still cached by browser

Comment: thanks, nice answer. but i want keep all info in database as one complete pack. very easy when host will be change or editing website map (architecture). i still searching a way to save all info in DB with cache ability.